# How to load all files from a directory?

Tags: c++, file, input, lua, io

Like the title says; how do I load every file in a directory? I'm interested in both c++ and lua.

Edit:
For windows I'd be glad for some real working code and especially for lua. I can do with boost::filesystem for c++.

Comment: load, run, locate. In particular with lua use the "dofile(s)" command for everything in a dir

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For Lua, you want the module [Lua Filesystem](http://www.keplerproject.org/luafilesystem/).

As observed by Nick, accessing the file system itself (as opposed to individual files) is outside the scope of the C and C++ standards. Since Lua itself is (with the exception of the dynamic loader used to implement require() for C modules) written in standard C, the core language lacks many file system features.

However, it is easy to extend the Lua core since (nearly) any platform that has a file system also supports DLLs or shared libraries. Lua File system is a portable library that adds support for directory iteration, file attribute discovery, and the like.

With lfs, emulating some of the capability of DIR in Lua is essentially as simple as:

```
require "lfs"
dot = arg[1] or "."
for name in lfs.dir(dot) do
    local fqn = dot.."/"..name
    local attr = lfs.attributes(fqn)
    print(name, attr.mode, os.date("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M",attr.modification), attr.size)
end
```

Which produces output that looks like:

```
E:...>t-lfs.lua
.       directory       2009-04-02 13:23        0
..      directory       2009-04-02 13:18        0
foo.txt file    2009-02-23 01:56        0
t-lfs.lua       file    2009-04-02 13:18        241

E:...>
```

If your copy of Lua came from [Lua for Windows](http://www.keplerproject.org/luafilesystem/), then you already have lfs installed, and the above sample will work out of the box.

**Edit:** Incidentally, the Lua solution might also be a sensible C or C++ solution. The Lua core is not at all large, provides a dynamic, garbage-collected language, and is easy to interact with from C either as a hosting application or as an extension module. To use lfs from a C application, you would link with the Lua DLL, initialize a Lua state, and get the state to execute the `require"lfs"` either via `luaL_dostring()` or by using the C API to retrieve the `require()` function from the global table, push the string `"lfs"`, and call the Lua function with something like `lua_pcall(L,1,1,0)`, which leaves the `lfs` table on the top of the Lua stack.

This approach probably makes the most sense if you already had a need for an embedded scripting language, and Lua meets your requirements.

Answer (score 4):

For a C++ solution, have a look at the [Boost.Filesystem](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/filesystem/index.html) library.

Answer (score 2):

Listing files in a directory is defined by the platform so you would have to use a platform dependent library.  This is true of c++ and Lua (which implements only ansi c functionality).

Answer (score 1):

```
require "lfs"

function loadall(dir)
  for file in lfs.dir(dir) do
    if string.find(file, ".lua$") then
      dofile(dir .. "/".. file)     
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: You should used `dofile` instead of `require` here: you're loading files, not modules.