# Lua file concatenation

Tags: lua

I'm trying to concatenate every file in a folder in lua to compile a bunch of logs into one master log and send it off to someone. I'm using the ifs library to iterate through every file in a directory, then reading it all in and trying to append it to the master file.

```
for name in lfs.dir("logs") do
    if(name ~= "." and name ~= "..") then
     local path = "logs/"..name
     print (path)
     local file=io.open(path,"R")
     print "2"
     local content = io.read("*all")
     print "3"
     io.close(file)

     local f=io.open("log.csv","A")
     file:write(content)
     io.close(f)    
    end
end
```

There are two issues.
The ifs library returns "." and ".." before the other file names [is there a better way to ignore these than an if statement?]
using the bit I found here: [How to load all files from a directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/710253/how-to-load-all-files-from-a-directory)

The important issue is that my command prompt keeps crashing when I test the file. It prints the path (a good one), then it crashes before getting to the "2" and I'm not sure why. The file exists and I can manipulate it by adding lines to it in another function.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid checking for `"."` and `".."` you should use `lfs.attributes` and its `mode` field to see if each item is a file or directory (or something else).

Instead of `io.read` you probably want `file:read` -- this might be the cause of your "crash."

I suggest you use `"r"` and `"a+"` for the `io.open` mode arguments.

Oh, and use `f:write` to write `content`

Comment: You should point out that `io.read` doesn't read from the `file`; it reads from a global file handle. A global file handle that was not opened.

Comment: Also, curious if "R" vs. "r" is interpreted differently and what the + adds for "a+", as I haven't seen that before.

Comment: Re: lower case mode arguments... that's how they're documented at http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-io.open so that's what I'd use.

Comment: Re: "a+"... the Lua documentation is a bit misleading (to me); in retrospect I think you're better off with "a". Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3645123/opening-a-file-in-a-mode

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I didn't realize it wouldn't notify me of these comments too. Very helpful reading, thanks for the help. I think 'R' and 'r' both work the same, but to be safe I followed your advice :)